# Split a single stream into two lists

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a single stream `Stream<Acknowledgement> mappedRecords`, how can I split it into two two lists based on two filters? Here is my attempt:

```
List<Acknowledgement> summaryList =
    mappedRecords
        .filter(x -> x.getReportType().equals(summaryReportType))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Acknowledgement> detailList =
    mappedRecords
        .filter(x -> x.getReportType().equals(detailReportType))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code produces an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon
> or closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific filters you describe suggest a pretty clean way to do it, actually:

```
Map<ReportType, List<Acknowledgement>> lists = mappedRecords.collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getReportType()));
List<Acknowledgement> summaryList = lists.get(summaryReportType);
List<Acknowledgement> detailList = lists.get(detailReportType);
```

Comment: or `Acknowledgment::getReportType`